# Can a method implement multiple interface methods?

Tags: c#, interface

These are two implementations of interface methods and as you can see, they do the same thing *in this case*.

```
public override IList<IDatastoreRequestParameter> GetReadByOwnerIdParameters(int id) {
    return new List<IDatastoreRequestParameter> {
        new DatastoreRequestParameter("@CustomerId", id)
    };
}

public override IList<IDatastoreRequestParameter> GetDeleteByOwnerIdParameters(int id) {
    return new List<IDatastoreRequestParameter> {
        new DatastoreRequestParameter("@CustomerId", id)
    };
}
```

However, as we use this interface everywhere, sometimes they are the same but they can also have different parameters returned in the implementation. I know I can just create a private method to return the same thing, I'm just curious to see if it's possible. My gut tells me no, but SO is smarter than my gut, so here I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make one method and tell the compiler/platform to use it when calling two different methods. As you said, you can create a private method that will handle the case and call that, but you do have to implement the methods in the interface separately.

Comment: Or simply call the second interface method from the first.

Comment: @Ralf That is also a possibility, but it might cause a bit of confusion when reading code, depending on how it's done. For example, in this case if the `GetDeletedByOwnerIdParameters` would call the `GetReadByOwnerIdParameters`, one might wonder why the Read ones were Deleted also.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. It depends and mostly a private method is the most descriptive. If i would have problems given the private method a descriptive name (without lying) i would presumably tend to not try to create an artificial one and simply call the other interface method.

Comment: @Ralf That code I posted is the implementation I used. Creating a private method doesn't benefit me anything, really, being the code is next to nothing.